# use of different gradle commands

Tags: gradle, marklogic, ml-gradle

Here are a few commands of gradle that I came across:

```
gradle mlDeploy
gradle storeDeploy
gradle dmfCompileRules
gradle generateDMFInputSDM
```

Can anyone explain the use of each of these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

The names of the tasks already tell what they are supposed to do, don't they (at least while knowing what `ML`, `DFM` and `SDM` mean in the MarkLogic context)? And usually each Gradle task has a description, which explains what it does (or at least should). Just ask for `help`:

```
gradle help --task mlDeploy
gradle help --task storeDeploy 
gradle help --task dmfCompileRules 
gradle help --task generateDMFInputSDM
```

Comment: whats the difference between storedeploy and mldeploy ?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://developer.marklogic.com/code/ml-gradle/ ...or to answer your question in particular: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference (all these `ml` tasks come from that plugin), while `storeDeploy` may be the database/storage facility.

Answer (score 0):

Those last 3 all look like custom tasks that someone on your team defined in your build.gradle file.